# Count occurrences of distinct values across multiple columns and groups

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

I've got a dataframe like the one below (in the actual dataset the number of rows are a few thousands and I 've got more than 300 variables):

```
df <- data.frame (Gr = c("A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B"),
                  Var1 = c("a","b","c","e","a","a","c","e","b"),
                  Var2 = c("a","a","a","d","b","b","c","a","e"),
                  Var3 = c("e","a","b",NA,"a","b","c","d","a"),
                  Var4 = c("e",NA,"a","e","a","b","d","c",NA))
```

which returns:

```
  Gr Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4
1  A    a    a    e    e
2  A    b    a    a <NA>
3  A    c    a    b    a
4  B    e    d <NA>    e
5  B    a    b    a    a
6  B    a    b    b    b
7  B    c    c    c    d
8  B    e    a    d    c
9  B    b    e    a <NA>
```

and would like to get number of occurrences of each value (a,b,c,d,e, and NA) in each variable and in each group. Hence, the output should look something like the following:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Vars = c("Var1","Var2","Var3","Var4"),
                  a = c(1,3,1,1),
                  b = c(1,0,1,0),
                  c = c(1,0,0,0),
                  d = c(0,0,0,0),
                  e = c(0,0,1,1),
                  na = c(0,0,0,1))

df2 <- data.frame(Vars = c("Var1","Var2","Var3","Var4"),
                  a = c(2,1,2,1),
                  b = c(0,2,1,1),
                  c = c(1,1,1,1),
                  d = c(0,1,1,1),
                  e = c(2,1,0,1),
                  na = c(0,0,1,1))
output <- list(df1,df2)
names(output) <- c("A","B")
```

which looks like:

```
$A
  Vars a b c d e na
1 Var1 1 1 1 0 0  0
2 Var2 3 0 0 0 0  0
3 Var3 1 1 0 0 1  0
4 Var4 1 0 0 0 1  1

$B
  Vars a b c d e na
1 Var1 2 0 1 0 2  0
2 Var2 1 2 1 1 1  0
3 Var3 2 1 1 1 0  1
4 Var4 1 1 1 1 1  1
```

I haven't been able to make any considerable progress so far, and a tidyverse solution is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

We may use `mtabulate` after `split`ing

```
library(qdapTools)
lapply(split(df[-1], df$Gr), mtabulate)
```

If we need the `na` count as well

```
lapply(split(replace(df[-1], is.na(df[-1]), "na"), df$Gr), mtabulate)
```

-output

```
$A
     a b c e na
Var1 1 1 1 0  0
Var2 3 0 0 0  0
Var3 1 1 0 1  0
Var4 1 0 0 1  1

$B
     a b c d e na
Var1 2 1 1 0 2  0
Var2 1 2 1 1 1  0
Var3 2 1 1 1 0  1
Var4 1 1 1 1 1  1
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -Gr, names_to = "Vars") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = value, 
    values_fn = length, values_fill = 0) %>%
  {split(.[-1], .$Gr)}
```

-output

```
$A
# A tibble: 4 × 7
  Vars      a     e     b  `NA`     c     d
  <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 Var1      1     0     1     0     1     0
2 Var2      3     0     0     0     0     0
3 Var3      1     1     1     0     0     0
4 Var4      1     1     0     1     0     0

$B
# A tibble: 4 × 7
  Vars      a     e     b  `NA`     c     d
  <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 Var1      2     2     1     0     1     0
2 Var2      1     1     2     0     1     1
3 Var3      2     0     1     1     1     1
4 Var4      1     1     1     1     1     1
```

Comment: This is assuming Vars are of Character type, right? Would this be adjustable if Vars are of Factor type, hence a-e are factor levels rather than characters?

Comment: @sm1231 it works for the first case and third case, although in the second, it is just that we have to modify the values to 'na' from NA, then, you may need to convert to character i.e. `lapply(split(replace(type.convert(df[-1], as.is = TRUE), is.na(df[-1]), "na"), df$Gr), mtabulate)` or have to add `"na"` as one of the levels before `replace`ing

Comment: @sm1231 you may also add the `'na'` as levels before doing the second solution `df[-1] <- lapply(df[-1], function(x) factor(x, levels = c(levels(x), "na")))`

Comment: Two follow ups on this: 1) if we take data is numeric (hence, lets replace a-e with 1-5), is it possible to calculate  mean value for each Var and each Group? In the tidyverse solution, replaced values_fn = length by values_fn = mean, but it calculates column-wise means, which is useless; 2) Let's say there is another Grouping variable in the original dataset, Gr2, is it possible to group results by both in either solution?

Answer (score 0):

A `NA` save **base R** approach using `colSums`

```
val <- sort(unique(unlist(df[-1])), na.last=T)

as.list(lapply(split(df[-1], df$Gr), function(dlist) 
  data.frame(sapply(val, function(x) 
    colSums(dlist == x | (is.na(dlist) & is.na(x)), na.rm=T)), check.names=F)))
$A
     a b c d e NA
Var1 1 1 1 0 0  0
Var2 3 0 0 0 0  0
Var3 1 1 0 0 1  0
Var4 1 0 0 0 1  1

$B
     a b c d e NA
Var1 2 1 1 0 2  0
Var2 1 2 1 1 1  0
Var3 2 1 1 1 0  1
Var4 1 1 1 1 1  1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
reshape2::recast(df,Gr+variable~value,length,id.var = 'Gr')

  Gr variable a b c d e NA
1  A     Var1 1 1 1 0 0  0
2  A     Var2 3 0 0 0 0  0
3  A     Var3 1 1 0 0 1  0
4  A     Var4 1 0 0 0 1  1
5  B     Var1 2 1 1 0 2  0
6  B     Var2 1 2 1 1 1  0
7  B     Var3 2 1 1 1 0  1
```

If you must split them:

```
split(reshape2::recast(df,Gr+variable~value,length,id.var = 'Gr'), ~Gr)

$A
  Gr variable a b c d e NA
1  A     Var1 1 1 1 0 0  0
2  A     Var2 3 0 0 0 0  0
3  A     Var3 1 1 0 0 1  0
4  A     Var4 1 0 0 0 1  1

$B
  Gr variable a b c d e NA
5  B     Var1 2 1 1 0 2  0
6  B     Var2 1 2 1 1 1  0
7  B     Var3 2 1 1 1 0  1
8  B     Var4 1 1 1 1 1  1
```

in base R:

```
ftable(cbind(df[1], stack(replace(df, is.na(df),'na'), -1)),col.vars = 2)

        values a b c d e na
Gr ind                     
A  Var1        1 1 1 0 0  0
   Var2        3 0 0 0 0  0
   Var3        1 1 0 0 1  0
   Var4        1 0 0 0 1  1
B  Var1        2 1 1 0 2  0
   Var2        1 2 1 1 1  0
   Var3        2 1 1 1 0  1
   Var4        1 1 1 1 1  1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another **base R** approach:

**DATA**

```
df <- data.frame (Gr = c("A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B"),
                  Var1 = c("a","b","c","e","a","a","c","e","b"),
                  Var2 = c("a","a","a","d","b","b","c","a","e"),
                  Var3 = c("e","a","b",NA,"a","b","c","d","a"),
                  Var4 = c("e",NA,"a","e","a","b","d","c",NA))
```

**PROCEDURE**

```
df2 <- split(df, f = df$Gr)

for (i in 1:length(df2)) {
print(t(apply(as.data.frame(df2[i]), 2, function(x) table(factor(x, levels=c(letters[1:5], NA)), useNA="always"))))
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
       a b c d e <NA>
A.Gr   0 0 0 0 0    3
A.Var1 1 1 1 0 0    0
A.Var2 3 0 0 0 0    0
A.Var3 1 1 0 0 1    0
A.Var4 1 0 0 0 1    1
       a b c d e <NA>
B.Gr   0 0 0 0 0    6
B.Var1 2 1 1 0 2    0
B.Var2 1 2 1 1 1    0
B.Var3 2 1 1 1 0    1
B.Var4 1 1 1 1 1    1
```